# How to generate a code for this kind of question?

Tags: python, python-3.x

.A list of numeric elements is given. Find the ratio of each element to the previous one. Select from the resulting values those that are less than 1.5. Calculate their average value. Input the answer by rounding the value to two decimal places.
l=[1.2,2.7,4.3,5.7,7.1,8.6,10.0,11.4]

I tried this code

```
I=[1.2,2.7,4.3,5.7,7.1,8.6,10.0,11.4]
ratio=[]
for i in range(len(i)-1) :
    local_ratio= I[i+1]/I[i]
    if local_ratio <1.5:
        ratio.append(local_ratio)
        print(ratio)
        sum=0
        for elem in ratio:
            sum+-=elem
            average=sum/len(ratio)
            print(round(average,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some minor mistakes in your code. You can use the following code.
Note: There is no need to compute the average value in each step.

```
I=[1.2,2.7,4.3,5.7,7.1,8.6,10.0,11.4]
ratio=[]
for i in range(len(I)-1) :
    local_ratio= I[i+1]/I[i]
    if local_ratio <1.5:
        ratio.append(local_ratio)
        print(ratio)
avg = round(sum(ratio) / len(ratio), 2)
```

Comment: it did not round the answer as intended , i want it like this Example 
l=[1,1.5,6,3,3] 
ratios: [1.5,4.0,0.5,1.0] 
ratios<1.5: [0.5,1.0] 
average: 0.75 
The answer: 0.75